# In javascript, are key value pair assignment is a statement?

Tags: javascript

I wants to know that in this code

```
 var a = {x:function(){},y:function(){}}
```

is x:function(){} a statement ?

Comment: That syntax is invalid, should probably be var a = {x:function(){},y:function(){}}

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not an expression, either; it's part of an expression. Specifically, the ECMA-262 [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) calls it a *PropertyAssignment* when defining the syntax for an object initializer expression.

Comment: +1 Correct, the specification makes it very clear what [a statement is](http://es5.github.io/#x12) . This is not a statement.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, in `{x:function(){},y:function(){}}` (without the assignment) `x:function(){}` _is_ a statement (well, `LabelledStatement` and then SyntaxError for an anonymous function declaration) ,  since it is read like a block - for the exact same reason `{}+{} = NaN` (the first part is read like an empty block so it's the same as `+{}` which tries to cast {} to a number, since it's not - it returns not a number).

Answer (score 0):

Well the definition of [statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29) is that it is is the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language.

In this instance `x:function(){}` is part of a larger declaration of `a` so **no** it is not.